# Implementing a Vector in a Queue

Tags: c++, class, vector

The vector displays just fine when it doesn't need to use the grow function, but as soon as the grow function is initialized the display for the vector goes crazy, here are the results

Output:

Grow function not initialized:

R

B

C

E

R

B

Grow function initialized by adding another element 'E' in this case

R

B

R

B

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class vector{

    public:
        void add(char);
        void display();
        void setSizes();

    private:
        void grow();
        int growthSize;
        int maxSize;
        int currSize=0;
        char * arr;

};


//initializes private variables
void vector::setSizes(){
    growthSize=2;
    maxSize= 7;
    arr = new char[maxSize];
}



//grows the vector
void vector::grow(){
    int *temp = new int[maxSize];
    //Makes copy of array
        for(int i=0;i<maxSize;i++){
            temp[i]=arr[i];
        }

    delete arr;

    int *arr = new int[maxSize+growthSize];
        for(int i= 0; i<maxSize; i++){
        arr[i]= temp[i];
        }

    delete temp;
    maxSize= maxSize + growthSize;
    cout<< "The array grew by " << growthSize << " elements."<< endl;
    }



//adds to the vector
void vector::add(char insert){
    arr[currSize]=insert;
    currSize++;
    if(currSize == maxSize){
        grow();
    }

}



void vector::display(){
    for(int i=0;i<currSize;i++){

        cout<<arr[i]<< endl;

    }

}


 int main(){

    vector bill;
    bill.setSizes();
    bill.add('R');
    bill.add('B');
    bill.add('C');
    bill.add('E');
    bill.add('R');
    bill.add('B');
    bill.add('E');

    bill.display();






}
```

Comment: arr[currSize]=insert;
You are assigning before checking the size ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
int *arr = new int[maxSize+growthSize];
```

hides the declaration of `arr` in the class, so you are then just working with a local variable.

Comment: Additionally, the `delete`s should be array `delete[]`s to avoid potential memory corruption. And, the newly allocated `arr` is `int[]` while the class member is `char[]`.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't completely understand what you are telling me to replace

Comment: Don't put the `int *` in the line above. That declares a new local variable, which means that your code is no longer changing the `arr` member variable of your class.

Comment: The program still fails after removing the int * 
Heres the error:[Error] cannot convert 'int*' to 'char*' in assignment

Comment: That would be because `arr` is a `char *` and `new int[maxSize+growthSize];` makes an `int *`. You should be using `new char[maxSize+growthSize];` to match your declaration.

Comment: How could I be so foolish!Thank you for the help